# Apply function onclick function on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 divs that fades sequentially on page load just like on this link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/x4qjscgv/6/ However, I want the fade function to happen once the user clicked a button. I tried to use the function: document.getElementById but it does not appear to be working.

See full code below:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.word1, .word2, .word3').each(function(fadeIn) {
    $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
  });
});

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e)

</script>

<style>
    #chat {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<button id="btn"> fade divs </button>

<div id="chat" class="word1">Word 1</div>
<div id="chat" class="word2">Word 2</div>
<div id="chat" class="word3">Word 3</div>


<div id="" class="">Word 4</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery? Second, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake adding the local version of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow my example. But note, id is only one instance, and class can has many instances!

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.word1, .word2, .word3').each(function(fadeIn) {
      $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
  
  $("#btn").on('click', function(e){
    $('.word1, .word2, .word3').each(function(fadeIn) {
      $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
  $("#btnhide").on('click', function(e){
    $('.chat').hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<style>
  .chat {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="btn"> fade divs </button> <button id="btnhide"> hide divs</button>
  
  <div class="chat word1">Word 1</div>
  <div class="chat word2">Word 2</div>
  <div class="chat word3">Word 3</div>
  
  
  <div id="" class="">Word 4</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does select `#btn`, however it does not execute anything because the function declaration is incomplete:
`document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e)`

You must include the actions of the function like so:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e){
    // add function within curly braces.
}
```

It's worth noting that the `e` is the [Event object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp). Try adding `console.log('test')` and check the console (often accessed via right-click > "Inspect") for your messages.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick function that you used indeed doesn't do anything, because you didn't wrapped your'e fade-in code by it. If you already using jquery, try using the [click event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/), like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click( function () {
        $('.word1, .word2, .word3').each(function(fadeIn) {
            $(this).delay(fadeIn * 500).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Modify your example:

```
<div id="chat1" class="word">Word 1</div>
<div id="chat2" class="word">Word 2</div>
<div id="chat3" class="word">Word 3</div>

.word {
  display: none;
}

$(".word").click(function(e){
    $(this).delay(10).fadeOut(1000); 
});
```